# "ReflectionClass: Pagescontroller Does Not Exist" Error

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

I have a laravel 5.7 app which works very well on my local server. But on deploying it to shared cpanel server and haven made the necessary correction on the index.php page, I still get this error that Pagescontroller Does Not Exist.
Please I will need help.

Below are the error code:

/home/ondi/miniblog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php
    }

```
/**
 * Instantiate a concrete instance of the given type.
 *
 * @param  string  $concrete
 * @return mixed
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
 */
public function build($concrete)
{
    // If the concrete type is actually a Closure, we will just execute it and
    // hand back the results of the functions, which allows functions to be
    // used as resolvers for more fine-tuned resolution of these objects.
    if ($concrete instanceof Closure) {
        return $concrete($this, $this->getLastParameterOverride());
    }

    $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
```

Arguments

1. "Class App\Http\Controllers\pagescontroller does not exist"

Comment: You said `Pagescontroller` but the error is `pagescontroller`. On linux capitalization matters

Comment: Hands up!!!!!!!!!!! @ cbaconnier. Thank you so, so much!!!!!!!!!!. You have just saved my of over one week error. I just changed the upper case to lower case, and that's it. It works at ones. Thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer and felt should drop it here for those with similar issue. I just followed cbaconnier's instruction on changing the uppercase to lowercase. And that's it, it loaded at once.

Fact is that i saved my pagescontroller (which is found in: app/Http/controllers/pagescontroller) with PagesController. That's where my problem was coming from all those while. So immediately I changed it from "PagesController" to "pagescontroller". The site loaded at ones.